# Why is a small Excel VBA Macro is running extremely slow

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a short macro to hide all customers that have no current sales for the current year. The YTD sales are in the K column (specifically K10-250). Those cells use a vlookup to pull data from another tab where we dump data. My question is why on earth would this macro take 10-15minutes to run? I have a similar macro on another spreadsheet that takes only 2-3 minutes for over 1,500 rows. I have already turned off screen updating. I can't think of anything else that would speed it up.

```
   Sub HideNoSlackers()
'
' HideNoSlackers Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
 Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Select
 Dim cell As Range
 For Each cell In Range("K10:K250")
   If cell.Value = 0 Then
     cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Else
     cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your macro, try turning off the add-ins and running.  Does this speed it up?

Comment: If you have code that triggers worksheet events, turn it off with `application.EnableEvents = False` and back to `True` when you are done.

Comment: This may not help, but try setting the calculation mode to manual while you are doing this so that your changes don't force a recalc of the entire sheet.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I don't think recalculation happens when hidding/showing cells.

Comment: if you put a auto-filter on and filter it that way - does that also take so Long? If yes you have a problem with your data/formulas; If no you have a Problem with your macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want the calculation to be set Manual before hiding the rows? Also you can get rid of `If` statements in your case. Try this:

```
Sub HideNoSlackers()
    Dim cell As Range, lCalcState As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Record the original Calculation state and set it to Manual
    lCalcState = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Range("K10:K250")
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value = 0)
    Next
    ' Restore the original Calculation state
    Application.Calculation = lCalcState
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Don't forget set ScreenUpdating back to True!
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub HideNoSlackers()
 Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rngHide As Range

    Set rng = Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Range("K10:K250")
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rngHide = Application.Union(rngHide, cell)
            Else
                Set rngHide = cell
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this with a macro?

If you create a table over the data, you can set up a filter on the sales column that will show only those where sales<> 0.

Macros are useful in excel but the majority of actions that people turn to macros for can be done natively in excel.

Answer (score 1):

there must be something else that's wrong. Try without .Selecting the sheet but that's not a huge improvement

Note rows are visible by default so the Else statement should be optional really.

```
Sub HideNoSlackers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Range("K10:K250")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would think the else statement should be kept if this is run weekly then if a company makes a sales and has input it would never unhide the row.

Comment: @Sorceri If he adds a `Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False` after the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then all the rows will become visible

Answer (score 1):

the shortest code to achieve the same Goal in a very different way:

```
Sub column_K_not_NULL
    Sheets("CONSOLIDATED DATA").Select
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then Selection.AutoFilter 'if an autofilter already exists this is removed
    ActiveSheet.Range("$K$10:$K$250").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
End Sub
```

of course you could put in the standard minimums like

```
application.calculation = Manual 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and other way round at the end.
Max

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling page breaks. I had a similar problem that would happen after someone printed from the sheet. This turned on page breaks, and subsequent runs of the script would take forever.

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

Answer (score 0):

We found out, that the program Syncplicity in the Version 4.1.0.1533 slows down macros up to 15times slower because events trigger syncplicity.

with

Application.EnableEvents = False

;do your job here

Application.EnableEvents = True

the speed is back.