# Speed of Code - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following code takes a look at Named Ranges and either hides them or unhides them depending on the button caption.  The problem is it takes entirely too long.  From 2 to 5 seconds.  I put the same code into a new book and it runs instantly.  Is there anything I should look at that could be causing this or any particular trouble shooting steps?  (Obviously the new workbook is missing 99% of the rest of the code, but I just wanted to confirm that it CAN run that fast)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
If UnhideButton.Caption = "Hide all premium rows" Then
        For i = 1 To 5
        QuoteReport.Range("hidesubs" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Next i
    UnhideButton.Caption = "Unhide"
Else
    QuoteReport.Range("hideblanks").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'Hide premium by coverage layer
    For Each c In QuoteReport.Range("HideBlanks").Cells
        If Not IsError(c.Value) Then
            If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    UnhideButton.Caption = "Hide"
End If
```

Comment: Could be that the range is not correctly set. My guess: if ALL the ranges in a worksheet have to be scanned, it CAN take from 2 to 5 seconds.

Comment: well, how BIG is this range `QuoteReport.Range("HideBlanks").Cells`?

Comment: Are both the outside `If` and `Else` slow, or just one of the two?

Comment: Have you got a Worksheet_Change() Event running in this workbook by any chance...?

Comment: @Noldor130884 It's only looking at a maximum of 5 Named Ranges. 1 of them is about 50 cells long.

Comment: @RintzeZelle Both are slow, but the Else is taking 4-5 seconds as opposed to 1 for the If Statement.

Comment: You can add a handful of `Debug.Print Timer & " My description"` lines to pinpoint the slowdown. This might give you additional clues on what you can optimize...

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=144006 suggests using `ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False` during the macro. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905724/why-is-a-small-excel-vba-macro-is-running-extremely-slow.

Comment: @DMcCallister I didn't say that the range was incredibly big, what I did say, is that in one worksheet could be bugged so that many more cells are included in that range...

Comment: if you have multiple empty cells on the same row, it will hide the entire row multiple times. To avoid that you can use a double loop For y=1 to Rg.rows.count , and then for x (comulms) . if a blank cell is found, hide rows(y) and EXIT FOR (ignoring all other x on this row)